# How can I get `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` to lint functional components that are exported as `default`?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks, typescript-eslint

I have deliberately created a simple functional component that breaks the rules of hooks. It contains the following snippet.

```
  if (Math.rand > 0.5) {
    const [name, setName] = useState("fred");
  }
```

I expect that `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` would lint this clear mistake, but it doesn't. After trying to get to the bottom of this, I discovered that when I am exporting a function as default - the linter does not do it's thing. (I am using the `@typescript-eslint/parser` for what that's worth).

Is there any way to have the latter syntax work with `eslint`/`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, or must I always create a named functional component, then run `export default name;` beneath the function?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-demo-c10y2

Answer (score 2):

So... I just discovered that this is a known bug with `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`. Seems like you need to have a named function for the plugin to catch & lint your errors. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14404 (specifically just the `"react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"` rule).

Comment: From the comments in the thread it seems you have found a workaround for this. Could you update your answer to include the workaround, and perhaps accept the answer as a solution?

Comment: @NikolayShebanov the solution is to provide names for your react components. To avoid anonymous components. The linked github issue has a few examples.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is breaking the rules of hooks at which a hook must only be called at the top level of your code. It cannot be placed inside an if...else statement. Check out the rules of hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html